# Using symmetry to determine a hydrogen electron's decay route from $|300\rangle$ to $|100\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, group-theory

Lets say we have an electron in state $|nlm\rangle = |300\rangle$ of the hydrogen atom.  By selection rules, we know that it can only decay to ground state in 3 ways, namely through the $|21m\rangle$ state, where $m = -1,0,1,$ which all drop to $|100\rangle$ upon the next decay.  I would like to calculate the probability of the electron "passing through" each of the $|21m\rangle, \; m = -1,0,1$ states.  In other words, I would like to calculate the probability that the electron takes each of the following routes upon decay,
\begin{align}
|300\rangle \to &|21-1\rangle \to |100\rangle\\
|300\rangle \to &|210\rangle \to |100\rangle\\
|300\rangle \to &|211\rangle \to |100\rangle.
\end{align}
I know the answer is $1/3$ for each, by brute force calculation.  I was wondering if there was any symmetry principle that would allow one to conclude this in a non-hand-wavey way?

The brute force calculation involves computing $\langle 210|z|300\rangle$ and other nasty integrals so it would be of interest if one could "know" the probabilities of the decay route without doing such calculations.

Would this "equal probability of each route" result generalize to decay from any state? Say, $|400\rangle?$

Comment: I'm tempted to say that $m$ doesn't matter by rotational symmetry, but I don't know if that can be turned into a rigorous argument.

Comment: You need to read up on the Wigner-Eckart Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is using the [Wigner-Eckart theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Eckart_theorem). The way it is applied to your problem is as follows:
$$
\left\langle nlm |\vec{r}| n'l'm'\right\rangle = \left\langle nl ||\vec{r}|| n'l'\right\rangle \left\langle l' m' 1 q | l m\right\rangle
$$
where the second factor is a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient and $q=-1,0,1$ indicates the type of transition.

For the transitions that you wrote $|300\rangle \rightarrow |21m\rangle$, all the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are the same and equal to 1.

Since the Clebsch-Gordan factor does not depend on $n$ you can generalize this result to any $\left| n 0 0\right\rangle$ state.